# How to decrypt a receipt and validate for a Xamarin forms iOS auto-renewing subscription?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I'd like to know for a **Xamarin Forms iOS auto-renew subscription**:

- Is it mandatory to validate a purchase?
- How can I decrypt an App Store Receipt?
- How can I validate a purchase without using a server?

**VALIDATION**

I've had the app store reject my app saying I need to "validate on my server", but I've also read a lot of material online where people say a server is not necessary for an auto-subscription that simply unlocks a feature in the app and delivers no external content.

The Microsoft Xamarin documentation however doesn't describe this scenario and only considers server side validation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/in-app-purchasing/transactions-and-verification#Securing_Purchases

**DECRYPTION**

I understand the receipt is a PKCS #7 container and have read Apple's documentation on this but I'm not very knowledgeable on crytography and can't figure out how I can apply this to a Xamarin Forms iOS project.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/validating_receipts_on_the_device#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2

Could someone help with a Xamarin Forms, C#, app-side decrypt and validate example?

Comment: FWIW: Personally, if I did not want to maintain a server for an app, I would simply respond "yes its valid", rather than go through all the above. (If that is possible - I have not done local validation.) Then store in secure storage a list of purchases user made. On a jailbroken device, someone could alter that list. But if you aren't even affording a server, those customers (jailbroken phones) are not worth worrying about. Bigger risk is same AppleID used on multiple devices; Without a server, you have no way of tracking how many apple devices are using the same account...

Comment: ... if you have ever played any game which has in-app-purchases, try to login on two different devices. Game will instantly log out the first device, when second logs in. That requires a server. Apple's policy is that a user can "use software they have purchased on multiple devices they own" (or if their old phone breaks, and they get a new one, they can't be forced to re-purchase software). This means same AppleID on multiple devices gets to use anything purchased on that AppleID. Your only protection is server login, to prevent them running multiple devices at same time.

Comment: https://www.kodeco.com/5456-in-app-purchase-tutorial-getting-started looks like a good tutorial that covers the basics. I think their `IAPHelper` class can be modified to skip receipt validation. (You'll have to manually rewrite their java in c#. Put this in `MyProject.iOS` project - wherever your iOS-specific code is.)